# The cl tag — CL and OpenCL language, or MSVC C compiler?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

The tag [cl](/questions/tagged/cl) has just over 50 questions.

Many of them are about CL and OpenCL.

Many of them are probably tagged to represent the MSVC C compiler, `cl.exe`.

I've just rejected a suggested edit for a wiki that only allowed the MSVC meaning (with a custom explanation saying why, and saying it was time to discuss on Meta) — but it seems that other people thought it was OK.

What's best to do with the [cl](/questions/tagged/cl) tag?

*I note that there is a [opencl](/questions/tagged/opencl) with about 1300 questions; those questions about OpenCL could simply lose the plain [cl](/questions/tagged/cl) tag.  There are a variety of tags related to MS Visual Studio; I'm not sure if there needs to be a separate tag for `cl.exe` per se.*

Comment: I say blacklist it, and split the existing questions into three tags, `ibm-cl`, `open-cl`, and `msvc-cl`. Too much confusion could be had having just a single synonym.

Comment: There is no dash in OpenCL, and few people really know what the frontend executable is for MSVC.

Comment: The tag wiki for [cl] has now become MSVC-specific after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the 53, it seems the meanings of [cl](/questions/tagged/cl) break down like this:

- 36: cl.exe compiler
- 10: IBM's AS/400 Control Language (often appearing with [ibm-midrange](/questions/tagged/ibm-midrange))
- 4: OpenCL (often appearing with [opencl](/questions/tagged/opencl))
- 2: Common Lisp (should be [common-lisp](/questions/tagged/common-lisp)?)
- 1: [Mysterious/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709548/why-iterating-over-arrayiterator-ending-with-endless-loop)

OpenCL already has a tag, as mentioned, and the Lisp ones seem like a simple obvious retag. The two "legitimate" uses seem to be the Visual Studio and IBM meanings.

The [ibm-midrange](/questions/tagged/ibm-midrange) tag wiki references [control-language](/questions/tagged/control-language), which has 4 questions and 2 followers. Many [ibm-midrange](/questions/tagged/ibm-midrange) posts reference CL without any more specific tag.

If popularity is the relevant metric, cl.exe wins. On the other hand, [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio)+[compiler](/questions/tagged/compiler) beats the cl.exe usages handily.

I'm tempted to agree that plain ol' [cl](/questions/tagged/cl) may just be too vague to be useful, and all the questions should go to new, loving homes. The Visual Studio compiler would seem to be the obvious choice if [cl](/questions/tagged/cl) lives, though (and as of recently the tag wiki reflects this already).

Comment: Thanks for your extra analyis.  I've updated the Wiki entry to indicate that it shouldn't be used because it is ambiguous, and have put in the suggested tags for each of the ambiguous meanings.  I did leave the MSVC commentary behind in the main Wiki section, but it is a little bit of a sore thumb.

Comment: And all the `cl`-tagged questions are now not tagged `cl`.